# Ocaml function to convert a tuple into a list

Tags: list, ocaml

I have an (int * string) tuple which I want to covert into a list. The tuple is of the form (N, E) where is N is the number of occurances of element E. 
The function should return a list with N occurences of E in it.  Example is below. Lets assume this function is called tuple_decode.

```
tuple_decode (1, "A") -> ["A"]
tuple_decode (2,"B") -> ["B";"B"]
tuple_decode (4,"C") - > ["C";"C";"C";"C"]
```

The tuple_decode function is as follows

```
let tuple_decode acc (n,elem)   = 
let add_one_elem i = 
    match i  with
           0 -> acc
         | i -> elem :: acc ; add_one_elem (i-1)  (* Line 184 *)
in
add_one_elem n 
;;
```

when I try to compile this function I get the following error.

```
File "all_code.ml", line 184, characters 11-22:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
File "all_code.ml", line 184, characters 25-37:
Error: Unbound value add_one_elem
```

Could someone help me figure out why I get this error and warning.

Regards
Puneet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning comes from sequence composition using `;`. When you write `S1 ; S2`, the compiler expects `S1` to have `unit` type. But here `S1` returns a list (`elem::acc`) *whose value will be thrown away. Moreover, since you didn't pass `acc` as an argument, its value doesn't change after all recursive calls.*

The error is due to recursive use of `add_one_elem`. Because you didn't use `rec` keyword, when `add_one_elem (i-1)` is called, OCaml doesn't know `add_one_elem` is being recursively defined.

Moreover, `acc` should be a parameter of `add_one_elem` to accumulate results:

```
let tuple_decode (n, elem) = 
  let rec add_one_elem i acc = 
      match i  with
      | 0 -> acc
      | i -> add_one_elem (i-1) (elem::acc)
  in add_one_elem n []
```

Comment: Also, it is interesting to note that for the warning part, if `S1` does not have type `unit` then the result is thrown away. So if you don't pass the accumulator as an argument to your function, then the recursive call is useless.

Answer (score 0):

As @pad has already answered your question sufficiently, a nice solution would also be:

```
let decode (n, elem) = List.init n (fun _ -> elem)
```